# How to add AssemblySettings.dll.config file in a class library files in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, class-library

I have created a Class library file in c# named as AssemblySettings. Then i added Configuration files. When i build the project, in bin folder config files and AssemblySettings.dll.config file was created.Then i want to add assembly settings in AssemblySettings.dll.config. But in solution explorer .dll.config file was not created.  Kindly help me.

Comment: A DLL cannot have a .config file.  The CLR only ever looks for *one* .config file, its name is something.exe.config, the .config file for a program that's named something.exe.  Settings are pretty useless for DLLs if the EXE doesn't take care of initializing your DLL with its own settings.  You could consider a plain XML file that's stored in a well-known location.

Answer (score 2):

This file appears as `app.config` in Solution Explorer. The build process changes the name to NameOfAssembly.dll.config and puts it in the build folder.

Comment: Thanks. In Bin folder the NameOfAssembly.dll.config file created. But i want to modify that files in solution explorer. To add the assembly settings tag.

Comment: I build the project, In Bin folder the NameOfAssembly.dll.config file created.I want to see this .dll.config file in solution explorer.

Comment: This file is in the solution explorer, but it doesn't have the same name. It is called 'App.config'. This is the **same file** as AssemblySettings.dll.config. If you edit this file, when you build your solution, AssemblySetting.dll.config will be updated correctly. You don't need to edit AssemblySettings.dll.config directly.